# Python multiprocessing not working when used from C++

Tags: python, c++, multiprocessing

I'm trying to embed Python 3.3 x64 script with 'multiprocessing' to C++ code under Windows 7 x64.

Simple script like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def spawnWork(fileName, index):
    print("spawnWork: Entry... ")

    process = Process(target=execute, args=(fileName, index, ))
    process.start()

    print("spawnWork: ... Exit.")


def execute(fileName, index):
    print("execute: Entry... ")

    #Do some long processing

    print("execute: ... Exit.")
```

works fine from Python, but when embedded it stuck at .start() and locks.

I'm using all the relevant API calls to ensure safe GIL processing for Python. It works pretty well when not dealing with 'multiprocessing' package but locks when attempting to start another 'Process'.

Is it possible to use both Python/C++ mix and 'multiprocessing'?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly _how_ are you trying to embed it? Posting the relevant c++ code would help

Comment: Do you want the child processes to be running your C++ embedding app, or a normal Python interpreter? How much does your app act like a normal Python interpreter?

Comment: Also, this seems like the kind of thing only a few people really know the answer to. And, while Raymond Hettinger shows up here occasionally, asking on the appropriate mailing list, which he probably reads regularly, might be a better idea.

Comment: The C/C++ code is trivial like using 'Py_Initialize', 'PyImport_ImportModule' etc. Everything works well right before I add multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect this to work, as the way `multiprocessing` works on Windows (where there's no `fork`) is to `CreateProcess` another copy of the same executable. And since that executable is your embedding C++ app, not the Python interpreter, you will probably have to cooperate very closely with it to make that work. You can see the relevant code in [`posix_spawn_win32.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_win32.py).

Another potential problem is that on Windows, `multiprocessing` relies on a C extension module that fakes POSIX semaphores on top of Windows kernel semaphores; I haven't read through the code, but that could easily be doing something funky to GIL/threadstate and/or relying on something under the covers to share the semaphores with child Python executables.

Comment: This is what I suspected. I analyzed process.py and forking.py code and debugged deep inside and all the code logic seems to be not suitable for what I need.